# Using a formula inside of {} to create an array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

To prevent the XY problem - I have a half-dozen different grids I need to bring in and multiple for a single value, and each calculation is a single cell inside of a 120x600 table.

What I'd like to do is use sumproduct to help speed things along. Great! Sumproduct(A,B,C,D,E), and each set is a 1x6 array

However, C is giving me trouble. Instead of a neatly defined range or static values, I'm trying to calculate a set of numbers off of a set of index-match-matches, which in turn is referencing a 1350x600 matrix of its own.

Ideally, I'd like to do {Index(Match,Match),Index(Match,Match)....}, but that doesn't seem possible.

How can I get a calculate 1x6 array into my formula?

(Yes, this should be a database - and it is! The excel spreadsheet is acting as a backup/confirmation that the database is working properly)

For example: {1+2,3,4}, I'd hope to end up with an array of {3,3,4}

Comment: Could you share some sample data along with the Formula applied, help us to fix the issue !

Comment: what is your formula for this --> "Sumproduct(A,B,C,D,E), and each set is a 1x6 array " ?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the OP has moved on, but I was asking this question myself and came up with a somewhat kludgy approach to use a formula to define elements of an array in excel.

First create a series of N arrays of length N, each of which has one element that equals 1, with the rest of the elements equal to 0. The 1st array will be {1,0,0...}, the second {0,1,0...} etc.

Then, multiply the formula/name defining each element by the array that has a value 1 in the desired position, giving you something like `a*{1,0,0...} + b*{0,1,0...} + c*{0,0,1...}...` to give you `{a,b,c}` (where a,b,c... are formulas, defined names, etc.)

In the OP's example, instead of `{1+2,3,4}` to create the array `{3,3,4}` , you'd use `(1+2) * {1,0,0}+{0,3,4}`.